# Building Orbeon - Missing jquery libraries

Tags: intellij-idea, orbeon

I just updated to the latest Orbeon source from git. I am now getting errors saying that the following libraries are not found:

`SBT: be.doeraene:scalajs-jquery_sjs0.6_2.11:0.8.1-SNAPSHOT:jar` with path:
`C:\Users\myuser\.ivy2\local\be.doeraene\scalajs-jquery_sjs0.6_2.11\0.8.1-SNAPSHOT\jars\scalajs-jquery_sjs0.6_2.11.jar`

`SBT: org.webjars:jquery:2.1.3:jar` with path:
`C:\Users\myuser\.ivy2\cache\org.webjars\jquery\jars\jquery-2.1.3:jar`

Other libraries have been automatically downloaded to my `.ivy2` directory but IntelliJ is having trouble with these two. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this locally and found an issue in the build file. I pushed an update. Can you try again?

Comment: @ebruchez Thanks. That fixes the library errors. But now when I do a Rebuild in IntelliJ I get this error: `Error:Module 'core' tests: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: - is not a valid identifier`. Also, if I run the the `orbeon-war` ant task from IntelliJ I get this error: `build.xml:847: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sbt": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. If I run it from the command line I get `error: not found: type XFormsEvent` and others. Is it because IntelliJ's build failed so class files are missing?

Comment: See my answer to somebody else in the [forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Last-version-without-Scala-td4660374.html) about fixing up `scala-compiler.xml`.

Comment: @ebruchez Thanks. That resolved the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment from ebruchez above, I was able to resolve the errors based on [his answer in the orbeon forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Last-version-without-Scala-td4660374.html) and build successfully.